# Calculate support of given wavelet

Tags: wavelet-analysis

I am calculating approximations using wavelets but outside the multi resolution analysis framework; particularly, I am not using the built-in wavelet transforms.

Still, I need to calculate coefficients and therefore I am wondering how to calculate the support of a given *wave* in order to know where to start and stop calculating coefficients for `WaveletPhi[wave]` and `WaveletPsi[wave]` for a given resolution level. Therefore, I need to know the support for a given wavelet.

I suspect that I could use `WaveletFilterCoefficients[wave,"PrimalHighpass"]` and, similarly for `"PrimalLowpass"`; but it is just a hunch, not sure how.

Basically, I am after something along the lines of: `WaveletSupport[wave]` -> {a,b} support of given wavelet (For the moment just orthogonal wavelets, not biorthogonal).

Thanks.

Comment: What families are you using ?

Comment: I want to use `DaubechiesWavelet`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both the scaling and wavelet functions of the `DaubechiesWavelet` are compactly supported on the interval $\left [ 0, N-1 \right ]$, where `N` is the number of "taps", the impulse response length or just the length of the filter. Choose the one that suits you ^^ Bear in mind that the notation in *Mathematica* is slightly different - The wavelets are classified by the number of vanishing moments, rather than filter lengths, so the `DaubechiesWavelet[2]` has `2` vanishing moments and the filter length is `4`

There is another definition specifying the bounds of the support:

---

If the scaling function is supported on  $\left [ LB, UB \right ]$ then the wavelet function is supported on $\left [ \frac{LB-UB+1}{2}, \frac{UB-LB+1}{2} \right ]$

---

Just a simple experiment to confirm the statement (undocumented function):

```
ListLinePlot[Wavelets`ScalingAndWaveletFunction[DaubechiesWavelet[8], 
      "PrimalScalingFunction", 8, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision], 
      PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[Wavelets`ScalingAndWaveletFunction[DaubechiesWavelet[8], 
      "PrimalWaveletFunction", 8, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision], 
      PlotRange -> All]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sektor, but the support of second graph (wavelet) seems to be around [-6,4], isn't it? This is what confuses me, because the values for $x$ where $\psi _{j,k}(x)$ is guaranteed to be zero don't seem be just outside of [0,$2^{-j}$].

Comment: No need to ! :) Look again :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Sektor. Your comment about the "impulse response" got me thinking and I was able to arrive to something similar to yours using the "PrimalHighpass" coefficients (it is most likely the same, but I will double check with yours; fantastic.)

Comment: @caya Thank you for the question and I am glad to help :) BTW Do not hesitate to share something about wavelets or x-lets, in general - something you are working on, etc, if you can of course :)

Comment: Dear @Sektor, I have a question about defining a new wavelet. Could you help me :) The post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255195/defining-a-new-wavelet-fibonacci-wavelet