# Defining a new wavelet (Fibonacci wavelet)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, wavelet-analysis

I want to define a new wavelet (Fibonacci wavelet) in [the reference](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/oca.2549).
So, I read the tutorial on [Wolfram Site](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningYourOwnWavelet.html), @Jason B. ' s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/109660/44929), and also @Sektor 's [answers](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33820/44929).
But I still have some problems in my code while defining wavelet function in Eq. (6).
[image]

```
Clear["Global`*"];
g[n_, t_] := 1/Sqrt[Integrate[Fibonacci[n, t]^2, {t, 0, 1}]] Fibonacci[n, t]
FibonacciWavelet[]["WaveletQ"] := True
FibonacciWavelet[]["OrthogonalQ"] := True
FibonacciWavelet[]["BiorthogonalQ"] := False
FibonacciWavelet[]["WaveletFunction"] := g[#1, #2] &
```

**First Goal:** Where is the problem in the code above? When I run the following code; I get the error `WaveletPsi::bbdwave: The specification FibonacciWavelet[2] is not a valid wavelet specification recognized by the system.`

```
WaveletPsi[FibonacciWavelet[2], x]
```

**Second Goal:** I want to derive the followings:
[image]
The following code is right?

```
\[CapitalPsi][n_, m_, t_] :=2^((k-1)/2)WaveletPsi[FibonacciWavelet[m], 2^((k - 1)/2) t - n + 1]
k = 2; M = 3;
Column[Table[
Simplify@\[CapitalPsi][i, j, t], {j, 0, M - 1, 1}, {i, 1, 2^(k - 1), 1}] // Flatten]
```

**Third Goal:** Finally; how to save the new type of wavelet in order to use `WaveletPsi[FibonacciWavelet[m],x]`
as though the already defined wavelets (`DaubechiesWavelet` etc.)  Please [see](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WaveletPsi.html):

Comment: What is the purpose of your definition? Do you try to follow paper cited or do you try to follow Mathematica tutorial?

Comment: I am trying to follow the Mathematica tutorial about how to define new wavelets.

Comment: Definition of wavelets with Mathematica very differ from common applications like it described in the paper .

Comment: I understand. All right, how to write an efficient code in order to achieve steps in the post? What is your code suggestion?

Comment: I can recommend to use standard definition from the paper as it shown in my answer. The function what you try to define with Mathematica is useless.

Answer (score 3):

You need to (1) use a different integration variable in the integral (which is `Integrate`, not `Int`) and (2) use an [immediate assignment](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) in the definition of $g$ so that the integral in the denominator is not re-evaluated every time you request a wavelet.

Using [partial memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201001/26598):

```
Clear[g];
g[n_Integer] := g[n] = Function[t, Evaluate[
  Fibonacci[n, t]/Sqrt[Integrate[Fibonacci[n, s]^2, {s, 0, 1}]]]]
```

`g` now returns pure functions that are [memoized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization):

```
g[3]
(*    Function[t$, 1/2 Sqrt[15/7] (1 + t$^2)]    *)
```

Calling one of these with an argument gives the wavelet:

```
g[3][t]
(*    1/2 Sqrt[15/7] (1 + t^2)    *)
```

Now defining

```
FibonacciWavelet[_]["WaveletQ"] = True;
FibonacciWavelet[_]["OrthogonalQ"] = True;
FibonacciWavelet[_]["BiorthogonalQ"] = False;
FibonacciWavelet[n_Integer]["WaveletFunction"] := g[n]
```

you can request, for example,

```
FibonacciWavelet[3]["WaveletFunction"][t]
(*    1/2 Sqrt[15/7] (1 + t^2)    *)
```

Comment: Thank you. Your code works, but it is not what I exactly want. I can' t use `WaveletPsi[FibonacciWavelet[2], x]`  in your code.   I want to save the new wavelet and I want to use `WaveletPsi[FibonacciWavelet[m],x]` such as the already defined wavelets. (`HaarWavelet` etc.) Please see: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WaveletPsi.html

Answer (score 0):

We can answer Second Goal, since it has some meaning in connection with [the paper cited](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/oca.2549) (with application to delay problems). For second goal we have definitions of Fibonacci wavelets (note, first line can be extended to arbitrary `n`)

```
in = Table[Integrate[Fibonacci[n, t]^2, {t, 0, 1}], {n, 10}];

g[n_, t_] := Fibonacci[n + 1, t]/Sqrt[in[[n + 1]]]


psi[k_, n_, m_, t_] := 
 Piecewise[{{2^((k - 1)/2) g[m, 2^(k - 1) t - n + 1], (n - 1)/
      2^(k - 1) <= t < n/2^(k - 1)}, {0, True}}]

Psi[k_, M_, t_] := 
 Flatten[Table[psi[k, n, m, t], {n, 1, 2^(k - 1)}, {m, 0, M - 1}]]
```

With this definitions we can compute test example as follows

```
With[{k = 2, M = 3}, Psi[k, M, t]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Vector `Psi` can be used to solve some problems like described in [the paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/epdf/10.1002/oca.2549).